# Combining shapefiles in Python / GeoPandas

Tags: python, gis, spatial, shapefile, geopandas

I have three polygon shapefiles which overlap each other. Let's call them:

- file_one.shp (polygon Name is 1)
- file_two.shp (polygon Name is 2)
- file_three.shp (polygon Name is 3)

I want to combine them and keep the values like this.

[image]

How can I achieve the result (As shown in the figure) in Python, please?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what is your expected output. By combine, you mean just put all three files together and keep overlaps? Or any kind of spatial operation?

Comment: In the result , polygon one would be hollow, as would polygon two. Polygon three would not. I think I want to intersect them perhaps?

Comment: The inputs would be three files. The output would be one file with three features.

Comment: I would point you here at the moment http://geopandas.org/set_operations.html. You should provide some min. working example if you want a code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's generate some data for demonstration:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
shp1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [Point(1, 1).buffer(3)], 'name': ['Shape 1']})
shp2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [Point(1, 1).buffer(2)], 'name': ['Shape 2']})
shp3 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [Point(1, 1).buffer(1)], 'name': ['Shape 3']})
```

Now take the symmetric difference for all, but the smallest shape, that can be left as is:

```
diffs = []
gdfs = [shp1, shp2, shp3]
for idx, gdf in enumerate(gdfs):
    if idx < 2:
        diffs.append(gdf.symmetric_difference(gdfs[idx+1]).iloc[0])
diffs.append(shp3.iloc[0].geometry)
```

There you go, now you have the desired shapes as a list in diffs. If you would like to combine them to one GeoDataFrame, just do as follows:

```
all_shapes = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=diffs)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to simply create one shapefile from files you've mentioned you can try following code (I assume that shapefiles has same columns).

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

gdf1 = gpd.read_file('file_one.shp')
gdf2 = gpd.read_file('file_two.shp')
gdf3 = gpd.read_file('file_three.shp')

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([gdf1, gdf2, gdf3]))
```